# spring data jpa select query for super class field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data

I have a super class(which is not a `@Entity` or `@MappedSuperClass`) and sub-class entty class like:

```
Class A {
   @ElementCollection
   protected Collection<SomeEntity> someEntities;

// getter and setter
}
```

And

```
@Entity
Class B extends A {        
  private String name; 
 //getter and setter
}
```

I have written custom query to select name and someEntities like:

```
@Query ("select b.name, b.someEntities from B b")
```

It throws a exception in runtime saying unrecognized field someEntities.

Any solution were I did mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your super class is not `@Entity` or `@MappedSuperclass` (any reason for this?), then simply any field declared in it is not persistent, is not known to hibernate, and can not be used in queries. If you provide a use case, it could help us providing an alternative.